# Почему я не могу с помощью JS записать в поле input новое значение

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

Почему я не могу с помощью JS записать в поле input новое значение. После выполнение скрипта, там по остается значение полученное из th:field="*{name}".
Каким-то образом Thymeleaf блокирует запись. Но в тоже время я могу туда вводить данные вручную и менять это поле.

Вот код:

```html
<form name="form01" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/add-car/new}" th:object="${carEntity}">
    <input type="text" name="input01" id="inputVal" th:field="*{name}">
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="setVal()">Save</button>
</form>
<script>
    function setVal() {
        document.getElementById("inputVal").value = "Piter";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Кнопка `submit` по умолчанию вызывает переадресацию страницы.

Поэтому необходимо отключить это поведение с помощью `event.preventDefault();`

```html
<form id="form01" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/add-car/new}" th:object="${carEntity}">
    <input type="text" name="input01" id="inputVal" th:field="*{name}">
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
<script>
    //получаем форму
    const form = document.querySelector('#form01');
    //добавляем обработчик события на сабмит формы
    form.addEventListener('submit',setVal, false);
    function setVal(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //блокируем переодресацию страницы
        document.getElementById("inputVal").value = "Piter";
    }
</script>
```

Описание задачи:
имеется форма на которой отображаются данные объекта, пользователь может изменить эти данные и сохранить их, отправив на сервер изменения
Проблема возникла с полем input type="time", почему-то в нем не отображаются данные, я решил через JS занести туда значение, при нажатии на кнопку SAVE. Решение предложенное Daniil Loban, прекрасно работает для поля input type="text", но не записывает в поле input type="time", т.е. опять я пришел к тому с чего начал.

Comment: а если у меня на этой форме три кнопки, например:
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
...
это получается, что каждая будет вызывать это событие.
Как их отфильтровать в этом примере?

Comment: другие кнопки будут иметь type="button" и не влиять на сабмит формы

Comment: Почему у других type="button", у меня type="submit" у всех кнопок. У меня конечно слабые познания в html. Но как я прочитал: "Кнопка типа Submit сама отправляет данные формы на сервер, а для Button это нужно делать вручную." Или вот "внутри <form>, <submit> сама отправляет запрос на указаный в <form> аттрибут action а <button> нет ". На сколько я понял таже кнопка delete тоже должна быть  type="submit", т.к. она также отправляет на сервер номер Id.

Comment: если три кнопки сабмита то это они все смогут вызвать этот код и по event.target.id  можно будет получить id нажатой кнопки и обработать это соответсвенно. но насколько я помню вызов  event.preventDefault(); не вызовет экшен th:action="@{/add-car/new}" (впервые вижу префикс th: тут возможно это для какой-то либы) т.е. нужно убедиться что action сработает, если он нужен, по вопросу не понятно какая задача.

Comment: При использование этого кода возникло две проблемы:
1. почему-то не записываются данные в поле input type="time", в том время как в обычное поле input type="text" все прекрасно пишется.
2. th:action действительно не срабатывает, а это и есть отправка данных серверу. th - это тег Thymeleaf 
Описание задачи я добавил в вопросе

Comment: тогда нужно сделать иначе чуть позже скину код

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117476/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-alex).